# Cauchy's integral theorem using differentiation under the integral sign

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I came across the following extremely simple proof of Cauchy's integral theorem for analytic functions:
https://www.jstor.org/stable/27642307?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents

The proof uses differentiation under the integral sign but the author Peter Lax does not mention whether he is assuming analytic functions have a continuous derivative. Is the proof given by Lax valid if we do not assume continuity of the derivative?

Comment: An analytic function is infinitely differentiable.

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon, this being complex analysis, presumably "analytic" here just means "once complex differentiable on an open set"

Comment: @MarkS. Yes. Lax presumably means once complex differentiable but I am unsure whether his proof is valid without assuming the derivative continuous.